# How to use AVERAGEIFS() and <> in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an `omit` column in my spreadsheet so I can - obviously - omit that row from calculations. I mark rows to omit with `1`. I would assume this would work: `=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C4,B2:B4,"7/26/2022",A2:A4,<>1)`. Based on searches I've also tried `"<>1"`, `<>&"1"` and a number of other combinations. Most solutions show how to use it with `AVERAGEIF()` and not `AVERAGEIFS()`, which has a different structure.

Here is a screenshot to clarify. Expected output would be "4". Thanks
[image: AVERAGEIFS() example data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula worked for me:

`=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C4,B2:B4,"7/26/2022",A2:A4,"")`

[image]

Instead of getting the values that are not 1, I instead am asking for all the blank cells. This also means that you can use any character in the `omit` column and it will ignore it.

Comment: Ok you get the green checkmark for *technically* giving me a solution , but I still don't understand why <> never works for me . Thanks for your help Kaitlyn!

Answer (score 2):

I was creating the little setup also, but Kaitlynmm569 beat me to it.
I agree with Kaitlynmm569, though you might want to consider replacing the fixed date criterion with the contents of a cell.
That way you don't have to keep changing the formula, but only the 'input cell' instead when you want to:

[image: Dynamic date input with a fixed formula]

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C4,B2:B4,$F$2,A2:A4,"")
```